# Simplifying a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone show me the steps to get from:

$$\dfrac{\cos (x)}{1+\sin(x)}+\frac{1+\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

To:

$$2\sec(x)$$

Comment: For future questions, please dont use caps(titles like *HELP I NEED THIS TONIGHT*, or *THIS IS DUE TOMORROW*, although not uncommon, are not very welcome here). Also, this is not about calculus, and showing your effort might help you and the community to get better answers.

Comment: @chubakueno Understood!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do the obvious thing and combine the fractions over a common denominator:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}+\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}&=\frac{\cos^2x+(1+\sin x)^2}{\cos x(1+\sin x)}\\
&=\frac{\cos^2x+1+2\sin x+\sin^2x}{\cos x(1+\sin x)}\\
&=\frac{2+2\sin x}{\cos x(1+\sin x)}\;;
\end{align*}$$

from here you should be able to finish it.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x, \cos x\cdot\cos x=(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x) $

$$\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}=\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos x}$$

Comment: @Louis, how about this one?